# How to activate FormulaArray in Excel VBA without using Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply formula array in my excel vba program, but my formula array character has already exceed 255 characters, so I have to use replace method to replace the formula.

The result formula array is correct, but I always have to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to activate the formula, can someone else to teach me how to do in this situation?
I want to display correct formula array content without using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Follow is my code
My program logic: When user click and change the column, I will read the cells content and store the data in an array called ItemArray.

```html
Sub countItem(X, y As Variant)
 Dim ItemArray() As String
 Dim i As Integer, j, k, m As Integer
 Dim theFormulaPart1 As String
 Dim theFormulaPart2 As String
 Dim theFormulaPart3 As String
 Dim theFormulaPart4 As String
   If (Cells(X, y) <> "") Then
    
    '###split string and store in array###'
     
     ItemArray = Split(Cells(X, y), "+")
  
      theFormulaPart1 = "=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF("
      theFormulaPart3 = ",$B4:$B81,"""" ))"
   
      For j = 0 To UBound(ItemArray)
        theFormulaPart2 = theFormulaPart2 & "+" & "((E4:E81=" & ItemArray(j) & ")+0)"
        
      Next j
        theFormulaPart4 = "X()" & theFormulaPart2 & "Y()"
        
        With Cells(X + 3, 5)
        .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart4
        .Replace "Y()", theFormulaPart3
        .Replace "X()", theFormulaPart1
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't tested but suspect it's because you aren't entering the formula with an `=` sign initially.

Comment: May be you are right, I try it.

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for your recommendation!!  I solved this problem, the formula array result has already displayed as my expectation.  Thanks :)